# Como usar o Boostrap na opção `Trecho de código`

Tags: suporte, stack-snippets

Quero fazer uma pergunta, e incluir um `Trecho de código` para melhor visualização, mas meu CSS usa o Bootstrap, qual procedimento à fazer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tentou adicionar isto no HTML?

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Ou tentou usar o botão "Adicionar biblioteca externa" com esses endereços? É para funcionar.

Comment: Sabe qual a biblioteca externa do bootstrap?

Answer (score 6):

No **Stack Snippet** (trecho de código) recomendo que use o mesmo CDN que o Bootstrap sugere: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn, isso evitará com que o exemplo pare de funcionar acaso esteja usando um servidor alternativo que venha a ficar offline.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Inclua este **somente** se for interagir com a API do bootstrap, por exemplo abrir modais após clicar em um link:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Nota se for adicionar bootstrap.min.js, adicione também o jquery clicando em:
>
> [image: jquery]

Se não for usar a API realmente creio que é desnecessário, por exemplo se o efeito que pretende passar no exemplo é apenas a responsividade o Js é dispensável.

Se precisar da API:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc</div>
```

Se só precisar dos efeitos CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc Etc</div>
```

Comment: é, eu comentei e já deletei em seguida, mas deve ter ficado no seu inbox

Comment: @Bacco só para entoar a minha intenção, eu formulei a resposta, porque era necessário destacar a necessidade do jQuery e quando é necessário adicionar o bootstrap.js e quando não é ;)